# Format String vulnerability

Tags: c, string, security, scanf

I have simple C program:

```
char user_input[100];
scanf("%s", user_input);
printf(user_input);
```

It is my understanding this represents security vulnerability; e.g. inputing a bunch of %x will print out the stack's content.

But how could one print a chosen memory location?

I read that:

```
\x10\x01\x48\x08_%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x|%s|
```

Should be dumping the memory's content at the location 0x08480110 from [this paper](http://crypto.stanford.edu/cs155/papers/formatstring-1.2.pdf). But instead, it is printing out the very next 4bytes to the format string on the stack. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: This is a forest of trees question, input more than 99 characters to invoke a buffer overflow.  The Little Bobby Tables story of not sanitizing input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string itself will be on the stack (as you've declared `user_input` as a local variable).  So if you walk the stack far enough (which is what the `%08x` force `printf` to do), then you will eventually arrive at the beginning of the format string.  `%s` tells `printf` to read an address from the stack, and then print the string found at that location.  So it reads the first 4/8 bytes of the format string, and uses those as the address.

Of course, for this to work, you need to know exactly how far to read through the stack in order to hit the format string.  So you may need to adjust the number of `%08x`.

Also, a user entering `\x10` at run-time is not the same as a string literal in your source code that contains `\x10`...

Comment: Is the format string not lower in memory than user_input is? Also, I understand that %x "walks the stack", is there a way to not have the entire content of the stack printed out, i.e. A way to walk the stack up to the format string which will use the first 4 bytes as the address it has to read from the stack, but, without printing out everything in between?

Comment: @Pi_: It depends.  On x86, the stack typically grows downwards (so `printf`'s stack frame will be at a lower address than the caller's stack frame).

Comment: NOTE: I found that the input "%n$x" where n is an integer is going through the first n-1 iterations without printing out the result (i.e. it is popping the n-1 iterations and directly goes to the n's iteration)

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in great detail in [Exploiting Format String Vulnerabilities.](http://julianor.tripod.com/bc/formatstring-1.2.pdf)

If you want a picture, see Section 4.4 of these [lecture notes](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs261-f07/scribenotes/0906-dk.pdf).